# Glagolitic Ⰾ (l) is like Ⰴ (d). Is it related to Latin / Old Latin l / d lingua dingua, lacrima dacrima?

Tags: writing-systems, slavic-languages

Glagolitic Ⰾ (l) is like Ⰴ (d). Is it related to Latin / Old Latin l / d lingua dingua, lacrima dacrima?

Comment: A couple of side comments: it's been argued that the initial /l~d/ variation in Latin was an Etruscan influence, and the two sounds are moderately similar and we see relationships between them all over the world (for example, they're thought to have been allophones in Proto-Bantu).

Comment: (In this particular case, of course, there's no phonological reason for the connection, as jk points out. But if you're interested in the relationship between /l/ and /d/ in general, Bantu is a good place to look.)

Answer (score 8):

Definitely not.

The similarity of the Glagolitic glyphs is directly inherited from the similarity of the Greek letters Delta (Δ) and Lambda (Λ). Also for the Greek letter shapes there is no apparent linguistic motivation, they are just arbitrary and inherited themselves from the Phenician alphabet.

For some details see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet#History)